# Kickstart @ Apache spark using java

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, apache-spark

Can any one explain to me the below code? The log data contain many lines of read me data. Since I'm new to java and Apache spark i feel bit difficult in understanding the code.

```
JavaRDD<String> words = logData
                .flatMap(new FlatMapFunction<String, String>() {
                    public Iterable<String> call(String line) {
                        return Arrays.asList(line.split(" "));
                    }
                });
```

Comment: can any one please explain me clearly the above code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code takes an RDD, which you can think of as a distributed collection, and applies the flatMap operator on it. This results in a new RDD. In this case the function that is passed in to the flatMap operator will, for each string in the source RDD, product a list of each the words in the input string. flatMap works very similar to map except it also flattens the result, instead of getting back an RDD of lists of words, we just get back an RDD with the words. This would normally be one of the first steps to doing a word count or something similar.

Comment: can u please explain me clearly about "PairFunction and Function"

Comment: I don't find any documentation for the available methods applied for a JavaRDD<String> string say for example I'm not clear about ".filter, .mapToPair, .reduceByKey) methods is there any site which tells clearly abiut the functioning and usage of those methods

Comment: PairFunction is used for when we want to convert a JavaRDD to a JavaPairRDD. JavaPairRDDs consist of key value pairs, hence the names mapToPair, and PairFunction and so on.

Comment: You may wish to look at the Spark Programming guide http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/programming-guide.html  and the corresponding JavaDocs http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/java/index.html .